# MongoDB Duplicate Key Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

So right now, I'm working on a service to allow multiple events to store data on MongoDB. They store event data by creating new collections on MongoDB every time a new event comes on. If the same event needs to store a different set of data, a new document in MongoDB should be created.

The code below is the service I created to handle this.

```
import WhiteBoardEvent from '../model/event.model';
import IEventStore from '../interface/eventStore.interface';
import * as MongoClient from 'mongodb';

export class EventStore implements IEventStore {
    private mongoDBEndpoint = "mongodb://192.168.10.10:27017";


    public insert(event: WhiteBoardEvent, callback: (err: any) => void): void {
        MongoClient.connect(this.mongoDBEndpoint, { connectTimeoutMS: 1000 }, (connErr, db) => {
            if (connErr) { db.close(); callback(connErr); return; }
            this.getNextSequence(db, event, (err, sequence) => {
                if (err) { db.close(); callback(err); return; }
                event.sequence = sequence;
                db.collection(event.roomId).insert(event, (err) => {
                    db.close();
                    callback(err);
                });
            });
        });
    }

    private createCounterCollection(db: MongoClient.Db, event: WhiteBoardEvent, callback: (err: any) => void): void {
        db.collection("counters").insert({
            roomId: event.roomId,
            sequence: 0
        }, callback);
    }

    private getNextSequence(db: MongoClient.Db, event: WhiteBoardEvent, callback: (err: any, sequence: number) => void): void {
        var collection = db.collection("counters");
        collection.findOneAndUpdate(
            { roomID: event.roomId },
            {
                $inc: { sequence: 1 },
                // new: true
            },
            {
                upsert: true,
                returnOriginal: false
            },
            (err, r) => {
                if (err) {
                    this.createCounterCollection(db, event, (err) => {
                        if (err) { callback(err, -1); return; }
                        callback(null, 0);
                    });
                    return;
                }
                callback(null, r.value.sequence);
                console.log("counter : " + r.value.sequence);
            }
        );
    }
}
```

The following code is a test file I created so that I can see the changes in MongoDB.

```
import * as timers from 'timers';
import WhiteBoardEvent from './data/model/event.model';
import { EventStore } from './data/service/eventStore.service';

var model = new WhiteBoardEvent();
model.name = "t2";
model.roomId = "testRoom";
model.timestamp = new Date();
model.userId = "";


var model2 = new WhiteBoardEvent();
model2.name = "t1";
model2.roomId = "testRoom2";
model2.timestamp = new Date();
model2.userId = "";

var eventStore = new EventStore();

var timer1 = timers.setInterval(()=>{
    eventStore.insert(model, (err)=>{
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }else{
            console.log("Test Completed!");

        }
    });
}, 1000);

var timer2 = timers.setInterval(()=>{
    eventStore.insert(model2, (err)=>{
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }else{
            console.log("Test Completed!");

        }
    });
}, 1000);
```

This is a snippet of the output I get. Here, "Test Completed" is shown for the first instances, after that, I'm getting the duplicate errors.

```
counter : 1
counter : 1
Test Completed!
Test Completed!
counter : 2
{ MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: admin.testRoom index: 
_id_ dup key: { : ObjectId('59d5da14cedd6f28a5db8c93') }
```

Can anyone help me with this? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating two instances of `WhiteBoardEvent` without explicitly setting an ID (this is fine, but relevant). Have a look at this excerpt from your code above:

```
db.collection(event.roomId).insert(event, (err) => {
    db.close();
    callback(err);
});
```

After handing `event` over to MongoDB's `insert`, it is checked to see if it has an ID - it does not. Because of this, the MongoDB code generates an ID for you (see [here](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/2.2/lib/collection.js#L738)). This is all great - it's what you want.

However, what happens the *next* time your `setInterval` callback is invoked? Well, `model` and `model2` now have an ID set - it was set according to the rules I just described. In this case, now that there's an ID set on the `model` going into `insert`, you are trying to reuse the same ID as the MongoDB code leaves it alone.

In your test code, you could simply clear out the ID in your `eventStore.insert` callback to ensure that a new ID is generated every time. e.g.:

```
eventStore.insert(model, (err)=>{
    model._id = null;

    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }else{
        console.log("Test Completed!");
    }
});
```

Comment: I found an alternative where I used casting.
it was like:

delete (<any>model)._id;

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that in your scheme you have you have a key set on `unique: true`.
Adding another object with the same key or a key not filled in will result in a duplicate key error. Because, if a field is not filled in it will be filled in with null. So 2 times null is a duplicate key error. To make sure this will not happen.

Use `sparse: true` instead of `unique: true`. Also note that a field with `unique: true` is never able to have two of the same keys. Sparse is only able to have multiple nulls(undefined) inside and works the same as `unique: true` further.

**In your case you have to times the userid on "", this will probably cause the error if its set on unique.**`model.userId = "";`

Hope this will solve your answer. Else please show us your model.

Sven